# using DataContractJsonSerializer when Json object propety is named with "@" symbol

Tags: asp.net, json, parsing, httpwebresponse, datacontractjsonserializer

When using DataContractJsonSerializer to parse a json response, I've come across a json object with a property name of @id and I can't seem to populate this field.  All of the other fields are populated without a problem. I can even get this field populated using Fiddler, but not using DataContractJsonSerializer. My code is as follows...

```
        public IEnumerable<Vehicle> vehicles { get; set; }

    public async Task GetVehicleList(string access_token)
    {
        vehicles = await GetVehicleListInfo(access_token);
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Vehicle>> GetVehicleListInfo(string access_token)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.example.com/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.example.api-v1+json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer" + access_token);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("vehicles");

            //IEnumerable<Vehicle> vehicles = new IEnumerable<Vehicle>();
            Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
            PagedVehicleResult pvr = new PagedVehicleResult();
            Stream dataStream = null;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                dataStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(pvr.GetType());
                pvr = (PagedVehicleResult)serializer.ReadObject(dataStream);
            }
            vehicles = pvr.vehicle;
            return vehicles;
        }
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// parent object returned by json.  contains list of vehicle objects
/// </summary>
public class PagedVehicleResult
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Vehicle> vehicle { get; set; }
}
public class Vehicle
{
    public int id { get; set; }  //This is the property in question.  
//When it comes back in fiddler it looks like "@id", and it does get populated.
//when it comes back in my console application it is 0 if int and null if string.
    public string vin { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string make { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public string deviceSerialNumber { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; } //consider making date?  unknown repercussions
    public CreateTimestamp createdTimestamp { get; set; } 
    public ModifiedTimestamp modifiedTimestamp { get; set; } 
}
public class CreateTimestamp
{
    public string readOnly { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; } //had to cast as string.. can convert to datetime before database insert
}
public class ModifiedTimestamp
{
    public string readOnly { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

How can I map that json @id field to my Vehicle class id property?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured this out on my own from reading various different post on the subject.

All I had to do was parse it into a json string first, then call a .replace() on the string to change the id.  Then I used the JavaScriptSerializer on that and it worked.

```
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                dataStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

                string content;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, true))
                {
                    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    content = content.Replace("@id", "id");
                    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();                    
                    pvr = js.Deserialize<PagedVehicleResult>(content);

                }                   
            }                
            vehicles = pvr.vehicle;
            return vehicles;
```

Now, when i try, my object id is correctly inserted.